# Querying large data set from Postgresql and processing

Tags: python, postgresql

My question is about memory and performance with querying large data and then processing.

Long story short, because of a bug. I am querying a table and getting all results between two timestamps. My Python script crashed due to not enough memory - This table is very wide and holds a massive JSON object. So I changed this to only return the Primary_Key of each row.

```sql
select id from *table_name*
where updated_on between %(date_one)s and %(date_two)s
order by updated_on asc
```

From here I loop through and query each row one by the Primary key for the row data.

```py
    for primary_key in *query_results*:
        row_data = data_helper.get_by_id( primary_key )
        # from here I do some formatting and throw a message on a queue processor,
        # this is not heavy processing
        Example:
          queue_helper.put_message_on_queue('update_related_tables', message_dict)
```

My question is, is this a "good" way of doing this? Do I need to help Python with GC? or will Python clean the memory after each iteration in the loop?

Comment: Please show details of the crash. PostgreSQL normally wouldn't have a problem with small result sets like that (the client side might have though). Normally the solution for large result sets is to use a cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must be a very wide table?  That doesn't seem like too crazy of a number of rows.  Anyway you can make a lazy function to yield the data `x` number of rows at a time.  It's not stated how you're executing your query, but this is a sqlalchemy/psycopg implementation:

```
with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(*query*)
    while True:
        chunk = result.fetchmany(x)
        if not chunk:
            break
        for row in chunk:
            heavy_processing(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty similar to @it's-yer-boy-chet's answer, except it's just using the lower-level psycopg2 library instead of sqlalchemy.  The iterator over `conn.execute()` will implicitly call the cursor.fetchone() method, returning one row at a time which keeps the memory footprint relatively small provided there aren't thousands and thousands of columns returned by the query.  Not sure if it necessarily provides any performance benefits over sqlalchemy, it might be doing basically the same thing under the hood.

If you still need more performance after that I'd look into a different database connection library like [asyncpg](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg)

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(user='user', password='password', host='host', database='database')
cursor = conn.cursor()
for row in cursor.execute(query):
    message_dict = format_message(row)
    queue_helper.put_message_on_queue('update_related_tables', message_dict)
```